# Why are my list items askew?

Tags: html, css, list, sass, nested-lists

So here's what it looks like now:

http://imgur.com/XaWsIja,wPmE0PX#0

Here's what I'm trying to get to (the design proofs):

http://imgur.com/XaWsIja,wPmE0PX#1

There's two problems that I've not been able to figure out here. There's this tiny little gap between logLeft and logRight. I want those list items to be flush against each other. And the other problem is obviously that I don't want logRight to drop off like that. I don't see anything pushing it down from logLeft, though, so I'm confused.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<section id="latestLogs">
<fieldset class="heading"><legend>Latest Logs</legend></fieldset>

<ul>
    <li class="log">
        <ul>
            <li style="background-image: url(/Css/images/temp/stair.jpg);background-position:center;" class="logLeft">
                <h3 class="logTitle">This is the Name of the Log</h3>
                <h4 class="logLoc">East Stairwell</h4>
                <p class="logDesc">This is the description of the log. This is the description of the log. This is the description of the log. This is the description of the log. This is the description of the log. This is the description of the log.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="logRight">
                <p>
                    Wednesday <br />
                    09.23.2015
                </p>
                <ul class="logCharacters">
                    <li>Opera</li>
                    <li>Alexandr</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="log">
        <ul>
            <li style="background-image: url(/Css/images/temp/waterbedroom.jpg);background-position:center;" class="logLeft">
                <h3 class="logTitle">This is the Name of Another Log</h3>
                <h4 class="logLoc">Room 302</h4>
                <p class="logDesc">Some log descriptions are very short.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="logRight">
                <p>
                    Tuesday <br />
                    09.22.2015
                </p>
                <ul class="logCharacters">
                    <li>Brandon (DM)</li>
                    <li>Rikart</li>
                    <li>Diego</li>
                    <li>Vaithen</li>
                    <li>Damocles Iota</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="log">
        <ul>
            <li style="background-image: url(/Css/images/temp/bathroom.jpg);background-position:center;" class="logLeft">
                <h3 class="logTitle">Some Log Descriptions Are Very Long Because People Just Keep Making Obscure References</h3>
                <h4 class="logLoc">10th Floor Womens Restroom</h4>
                <p class="logDesc">Some log descriptions are really long, like he just kept talking in one long incredibly unbroken sentence moving from topic to topic so that no-one had a chance to interrupt; it was really quite hypnotic. Some log descriptions are really long, like he just kept talking in one long incredibly unbroken sentence moving from topic to topic so that no-one had a chance to interrupt; it was really quite hypnotic. Some log descriptions are really long, like he just kept talking in one long incredibly unbroken sentence moving from topic to topic so that no-one had a chance to interrupt; it was really quite hypnotic.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="logRight">
                <p>
                    Monday <br />
                    09.21.2015
                </p>
                <ul class="logCharacters">
                    <li>Rekah</li>
                    <li>Big Ben</li>
                    <li>Fallon</li>
                    <li>Walker</li>
                    <li>Tseng</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="log">
        <ul>
            <li style="background-image: url(/Css/images/temp/lobby.jpg);background-position:center;" class="logLeft">
                <h3 class="logTitle">This Log Title is So Freaking Fabulous</h3>
                <h4 class="logLoc">Lobby</h4>
                <p class="logDesc">I wanted to write a long description, but instead I just copy and pasted this three times. I wanted to write a long description, but instead I just copy and pasted this three times. I wanted to write a long description, but instead I just copy and pasted this three times.</p>
            </li>
            <li class="logRight">
                <p>
                    Sunday <br />
                    09.20.2015
                </p>
                <ul class="logCharacters">
                    <li>Jarrett (DM)</li>
                    <li>Silver</li>
                    <li>Chastity</li>
                    <li>Trusken</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS (SASS, actually):

```
  #latestLogs {
    h3, h4 {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    ul, li {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .log {
            display: inline-block;
            li {
                display: inline-block;
            }
    }
    .logLeft {
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        .logTitle, .logLoc, .logDesc {
            text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000;
        }
        .logDesc {
            display: none;
        }
        .logLoc {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }
    }
    .logLeft:hover {
        .logTitle, .logLoc {
            display: none;
        }
        .logDesc {
            display: inline;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
    .logRight {
        display: block;
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
        background: rgba(10, 30, 32, .5);
        padding: 10px;
        p {
            margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
            color: $gold;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .logCharacters {
            color: $teal;
            font-weight: bold;
            li {
                display: list-item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both issues appear to be due to using `display: inline-block`. First you need to include `vertical-align: top` to correct the issue of the side columns being too low. Secondly `display: inline-block` adds a natural spacing of 1 or 2 pixels between elements. There are some hacks to correct this but in my opinion if you want the elements to touch you're better of using `float`

Comment: Without changing anything else, `vertical-align: top` fixed the issue with the second li going down like that. Good to know aout the spacing caused by `display: inline-block`... I will play around with `float` then. Thanks!